# Tail recursive average (arithmetic mean) in Scala

Tags: scala, mean, tail-recursion

I want to write tail recursive function that takes list of integers as parameter, and returns average(arithmetic mean) of that list.

example: mean(List(1,2,3,4))=2.5

```
def mean(as: List[Int]):Float={
        def helper(as: List[Int], accumulator_length:Int,accumulator_sum:Int):Float={
        as match{
          case Nil=>accumulator_sum.toFloat/accumulator_length
          case x::xs=>helper(xs,accumulator_length+1,accumulator_sum+x)
        }
      }
      helper(as,0,0)
    }
```

I assume that above function is completely tail recursive but, is there easy way to trace a function evaluation in Scala?

Comment: Your assumption is correct; the function as defined is tail recursive. With regards to tracing it, an easy way would be to use a IDE like Intellij and trace the recursive calls that way.

Comment: Add the `@tailrec` annotation. Then it will fail to compile unless it's tail recursive.

Comment: Do as Chris said. Here is a link http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.tailrec. Your telling the compiling that it is an error if this can not be optimised as a loop.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. Are you looking to confirm a function is tail recursive by tracing function evaluation? You can't, it's a compiler optimization. Are you looking to ensure a function is tail recursive? Use the `@tailrec` annotation and check `javap` if you don't trust it. Are you looking to trace function evaluation? Use a debugger or log statements. All these answers have been offered and rejected. Help us help you. We really want to! :)

Comment: I was looking for @tailrec , which Chris suggested. Thank you all for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way is to log your function's calls:

```
scala> @tailrec def mean(lst: List[Int], acc: Int = 0, size: Int = 0): Double = {
    |     println(s"lst = $lst, acc = $acc, size = $size") 
    |     if (lst.isEmpty) acc.toDouble/size 
    |       else mean(lst.tail, acc + lst.head, size + 1)
    |  }
mean: (lst: List[Int], acc: Int, size: Int)Double

scala> mean(List(1,2,3,4))
lst = List(1, 2, 3, 4), acc = 0, size = 0
lst = List(2, 3, 4), acc = 1, size = 1
lst = List(3, 4), acc = 3, size = 2
lst = List(4), acc = 6, size = 3
lst = List(), acc = 10, size = 4
res4: Double = 2.5 //this one printed by Scala REPL
```

So you can trace it without IDE

Comment: How does that prove it is tail recursive?

Comment: @Paul `@tailrec` assures it at compile time

Comment: I know it does. I just meant that the "obvious" logging of the calls in dk14's answer isn't really related to either the check of tail recursion or the "easy way of tracing a function evaluation", and hence this isn't really an answer

Comment: logging is the easiest way to trace the function evaluation, especially for Scala, which is still relatively young and has no such good debugging support as Java (at least in IntelliJ IDEA). P.S. If I understand it right, the question is about a "way to trace a function evaluation in Scala".